# Drag and drop of multiple items between views with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop, swiftui-list

I would like to implement drag and drop of multiple items (rows) in SwiftUI between two different views on iPhones, while also keeping reorder between sections. Currently I am using `LazyVStack` for it, but through `.onDrag` modifier only one `NSItemProvider` can be returned, which means that only one item can be dragged at a time. I also tried using `Lists` for this, but with Lists it is not possible to implement drag and drop between different List sections.

Is there any way to pass multiple `NSItemProvider` items into `.onDrag` modifier? Or any other way to implement drag and drop of multiple items between two views, while also keeping reorder between sections. I know this all is possible with UIKit (`UICollectionView`), but I am looking into opportunities of making it work with SwiftUI.

I've done a lot of research but haven't found any solution that would make it all work in SwiftUI, so decided to also ask here as the last resort. Thank you, any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Daniel no I ended up making it with UIKit back then:(